# mapkit annotations - displaying more than one location pin

Tags: iphone, maps, mapkit

does anyone know how to display more than one location on a map? i have a map w/ one pin at a lat/long point. I'd like to have pins for many locations.

another related question - if i wanted a map to display all McDonalds in the California, for example, is there a way to do this by feeding a search result from google maps into my app?

thanks in advance for any help/hints.

G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add as many MKAnnotation as you'd like, and you will see a pin for each of them. You can add multiple annotations at once by calling

```
[myMKMapView addAnnotations:(NSArray*)array];
```

instead of

```
[myMKMapView addAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)];
```